# Open new dynamic web project in java

Tags: java, servlets, amazon-ec2, eclipse-wtp

I'm writing server-application in java which needs to run on ec2 of amazon. I read somewhere i need to open **dynamic web project**, but i don't have this option in eclipse. my eclipse version is [image: eclipse].

I tried to install through help -> install new software the package "Web Tools Platforms" from http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/indigo
 but it failed in the middle of the installation.

Somebody can help me with that?

thanx!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the one labelled ***[Eclipse for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php)*** that one lets you create web projects.

Also see [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fccwebprj.html) & [this](http://besthowtodo.com/blog/2010/05/how-to-create-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse.html). It will help you..

Comment: Thanx.... i'll download the Eclipse for Java EE Developers, but i need to re-download all the sdk i already have? (android, aws...)

Comment: ***NO***, you don't need to re-install any sdk again...

Just download new eclipse from the link that I provided...

Comment: I download the zip file with Eclipse for Java EE Developers, what do I need to do in order to get all the sdk from the previous version into the new one?

Comment: right now I don't have Eclipse here on this machine so I won't be able to help you. Could you post new question for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Not all of them are required (I think), but after installing the components listed below I got the "Dynamic Web Project" template added to my Eclipse (Indigo). The list is:

- Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
- Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
- Eclipse Web Developer Tools
- Eclipse XML Editors and Tools

You can install those packages by clicking on "Help" > "Install New Software", selecting the repository that corresponds to your Eclipse build (i.e http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo for Indigo). The packages are grouped under "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development".